# Module not found even when added to sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import `test1.py` to `main.py` but it outputs this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Codes\Python\Test-Projects\modules\folder1\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import folder2.test1 as test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder2'
```

Here is my project structure:

```
modules/
+-- folder1/
|   +-- main.py
+-- folder2/
    +-- test1.py
    +-- __init__.py
```

Here are the contents of `main.py` and `test1.py`:

```
# main.py
import sys, pathlib

module_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[1].joinpath("folder2").resolve()
sys.path.insert(1, module_dir)

import folder2.test1 as test

test.hello()
```

```
# test1.py
def hello():
    print("HELLO WORLD")
```

I have verified that `folder2` is being added to `sys.path` but it still throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sys.path` entries need to be string. As stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> Only strings should be added to sys.path; all other data types are ignored during import.

2. `sys.path` specifies the **search paths** for names, not the actual names. So adding `folder2` to the search path won't make it accessible as a name. However in your case adding `modules` would result in `folder2` being found. Another way could be (if possible in your program) to change the import statement to `import test1 as test`. You can read more about Pythons import system [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)